# working in chrome and IE but not in Firefox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `p:commandLink` of `Primefaces`. Here, when i run this in chrome and IE in debug mode i m able to call this method but when i run in `FireFox` it is not calling the method at least it should call the debug point,it is also not been called, here is my code snippet.

```
<p:commandLink type="submit" immediate="true" 
    action="#{stockRoomReportManagedBean.fetchReplenishProducts(false)}" 
    styleClass="submitvalue" style="display:none;" />
```

Comment: <p:commandLink type="submit" immediate="true"
    action="#{stockRoomReportManagedBean.fetchReplenishProducts(false)}"
    styleClass="submitvalue" style="display:none;" />

Comment: Clear cache in Firefox. `Ctrl + Shift + Delete` or open it in private mode.

Comment: i m working in private mode only

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? If Mojarra 2.x, do you have context param `com.sun.faces.autoCompleteOffOnViewState=true` set in `web.xml`?